# How to use empties in a cloth simulation with geometry nodes

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, cloth-simulation, drivers, empty

i have set up a cloth simulation with six cloth objects, each is 1,5m wide and 6m high. I have placed three on the left side of a stage and the other three on the right side of the stage. To each (plane) i have hooked an empty to the top vertices and another empty to the bottom vertices. In that way i can move the cloth objects across the stage to create interesting backdrops for a music stage. I would move the top of one cloth to midstage while the bottom stays at stageright to create a diagonal cloth band for instance.

Now i want to move the empties more comfortable. The goal is to make animation of the cloth pieces easier. I would like to make a "menu" with maybe different "sliders" to move the top and bottom of the cloth, a button to keyframe the settings and a button which selects all planes, tabs into edit mode and then back in object mode again because the geometry needs to be "re set" in that way after you made changes, this is a workaround i learned while working with the cloth system, i assume this is a little bug in Blender.

What would be the right way to do something like that and can you explain me how to do it?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: Why do you want to use Geometry Nodes? Empty objects have no geometry. Yes, you can move them around with GN - but what is the advantage of using GN for this? Sounds more like a job for a Python add-on to me - or drivers or just keyframes. With GN you can neither create buttons and sliders nor keyframes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: thanks for your comment Blunder, obviously GN are not the right solution for that, i will look into drivers and how they can help me with that!